# SQL request with MAX DATE and Join statement

Tags: sql

I need your help please

I have 3 tables

Table1

```
ID, Price, Date, Address
-------------------------
1, 1.2, 02.01.2021, str. Abc
1, 1.3, 03.01.2021 ,str. Abc
2, 1.2, 01.01.2021, str. BFS
2, 1.1, 02.03.2021 ,str. Abb
3, 1.2, 02.03.2021, str. ABC
4, 1.3, 02.03.2021 ,str. aaa
5, 1.2, 05.02.2021 ,str. Abc
5, 2.3, 08.03.2021, str. Abc
```

Table2

```
ID, Code, Name
------------
1, 0, name1
2, 123, name2
3, 122, name3
and so on (doesn't matter these columns - they are unique)
```

Table3

```
AddName, Address
----------
AddName1, str. Abc
AddName2, str. BFS
AddName3, str. ABC
AddName4, str. Abb
```

and so on. It is names of objects at street. Also unique.

And i  need a table like

```
Name, Price, AddName, Date 
where Code = '{here is my variable}'
```

filtered by MAX possible date for the filed ID. So there should be something like

```
-------------------------------------
name1,1.2, AddName1, 02.01.2021
name2, 1.1, AddName4, 02.03.2021
```

Here we have 2 rows and selected date 02.03.2021 because it > then other values.

And so on

I tried

```
select Name, Price, max_date, a
from [Table 1] a
inner join [Table 2] b on a.ID = b.ID
inner join
    (select ID, Address max(convert(datetime, Date, 103)) max_date
     from [Table 1]
     group by ID) c on b.ID = c.ID 
                    and convert(datetime, b.Date, 103) = c.max_date
inner join
    [Table 3] on b.Address = [Table 3].Address
where
    a.Code = '123'
order by 
    max_date desc
```

but that doesn't work. I can easily make table I need but can't understand how to filter it also by date

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical approach assuming that you have analytic functions available:

```
with lastT1 as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as rn
    from Table1
)
select * from Table2 t2 inner join lastT1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rn = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd3df/10

Comment: ?date_argument
What does it mean? it is if i need manually select date. That doesnt suit. I need the newest date

Comment: @walfer You have notes about having a variable and then filtering by date as though you wanted to get "most recent as of". I guess I misread. Just remove that line.

Comment: thank u for your reply. It was good, but now issue that i cant joint 3rd table..

Comment: @walfer You can join as many other tables as you want. Why don't you give it a shot?

Comment: Doenst work. Joined 3 table and it is okay.
but i my t1.rn values dont have 1.
they are smthng like "12333","431232" and so one. It is simply like row number.

Comment: Edited. It is just row number from source table.

Comment: I accidentally left out the `partition by` part of the function. Try it again.